# WordPress Custom Permalink Structure with Custom Post Type and Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I searched for a solution everywhere, using plugin and without but I can't reach my goal. I have a Custom Post Type called "services", an associated Custom Taxonomy called "service-categories", and some sub-terms of the same Taxonomy. I want to create a hierarchical permalink structure. I need one of these:

1. /custom-post-type-name/term-name/(subterm-name)/post-name
2. /custom-taxonomy-name/term-name/(subterm-name)/post-name
3. /custom-post-type-name/custom-taxonomy-name/term-name/(subterm-name)/post-name

Thanks to all.

Comment: Can you name at least two solutions from the list of related questions you have tried without success? We have covered this problem so often, I don’t believe all of them failed in your case.

Comment: I would love to get solution 1 working. What do you suggest to do?

Comment: Look at the list of related questions in the sidebar right here.

Comment: I tried all the solution of the first result (wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/…) and others but doesn't work :(